# Should I down-vote an answer that works but promotes bad practices?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

Should [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18356813/531940) be down-voted even if it works but it promotes bad practices? *Bad practices* means it should never be done.

Comment: \*looks at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18360587/1350209) that encourages HTML parsing with regex\* I downvoted and people asked why. I said it was because regex should _never_ be used with HTML. I even linked to Zalgo, yet the people there still think it's good practice.

Comment: If you downvote an answer because you perceive some deficiency in that answer, then I'd say yes it's a legitimate reason for downvoting.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - over in _"this answer"_ it's good that you soon gave a link to a great explainer why that was bad practice.  @ pllee - along that line, agreeing with the two immediate answers below - I'd say down voting due for reasons of 'malpractice' :) should be a learning moment for both the bad answerer and those who follow.  For instance, even here, by reading the post Cole Johnson linked to, I learned something about REGEX that I didn't know despite decades of using it.  We learn by mistakes - the more mistakes people show us, the better we get at the trade, yes ?

Comment: Does this mean it is legitimate to downvote every answer that uses `mysql_*` functions?

Comment: Who should decide something should never be done?

Comment: Is it legitimate to downvote every answer that uses DOM parser because I think it is better to use SAX parser?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is one of those rare occasions where, if you *do* downvote, it's probably worthwhile to take a moment and explain in a comment *why* you are downvoting.  Otherwise, your downvote will make no sense on an otherwise perfectly good solution to a problem.

Regardless, votes are yours to do with what you wish, so long as you don't use them for abusive practices like serial or sock voting.  In general, a good rule of thumb to follow is this: *use your vote to express your opinion of an answer's usefulness.*

Comment: Explaining the downvotes is always good. I hate unexplained downvotes.

Answer (score 11):

YES!

Downvotes are for wrong answers. If the answer you speak of might work correctly, but should never be used, it is wrong, and should be downvoted. (-3 dims a post so people are less inclined to take notice of it.)

Do leave a comment to explain the problem, though.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I down-vote an answer that works but promotes bad practices?

**Yes, definitely.**

"It works" is not enough. (Often, it only appears to be working; something I often encounter when reviewing C or C++ answers is `printf("%d", sizeof(TYPE))`, which is undefined behavior, but sometimes it seems to work correctly.) An answer should not mislead people. If something "works" in some cases, but due to bad practices in it it won't work in a more general case, it deserves a downvote for sure.

**But: *the downvote is not for punishment.*** It would be good to comment as to why you downvoted, i. e. what is wrong with the answer. **The ultimate goal is to have the author of the answer fix his code so that it no longer suggests the use of bad practice.** If the answer is fixed, remove your downvote.

Comment: Personally, I think it would be better just to edit the answer to fix the problem. You want `printf("%zu", sizeof(TYPE));` That's way more effective than just downvoting because it actually makes the *correct* answer available to everyone and prevents perpetuating misinformation. Sure, you could hide the correct solution in a comment, but there's no guarantee people will see it. The only possible benefit in a comment is to educate the person who posted the answer. But since people are notified of edits made to their posts, they can still be educated. It also saves bellyaching about downvotes.

Comment: That goes for *small* problems like the one you mention, of course. I'm all for downvoting answers that are massively or irreparably wrong.

Comment: @CodyGray Definitely right - we are not even permitted to make edits that radically change contents.

Comment: Permitted by whom? That's a case-by-case judgment. I've made many such edits that I think were worthwhile. The goal of collaborative editing is to improve the contents of questions and answers. The reason we have a canned "too radical" rejection reason for suggested edits is so that we can reject edits that change the meaning of posts in an inappropriate way. Adding additional information, links, examples, etc., or fixing mistakes in code samples is all fine. There is no restriction on users with edit privileges doing this.

Comment: @CodyGray Recently I've edited an answer that was wrong. It said that "doing XY thing does Z" (or was it "XY thing is right"?) but it was very obviously wrong (it asserted the very opposite of the truth), so I've edited so it said the opposite and now it was correct. Then, the author of the answer rolled my edit back, and told me off arrogantly, stating that "feel free to downvote you f*cktard, but don't change my answer to the exact opposite" (or something like this).

Answer (score 3):

It would be more helpful to provide a separate, correct answer.

Comment: Agreed, but those two activities aren't mutually exclusive, so this is a non-answer.

Comment: @Asad pllee didn't answer the question which he referenced in the OP, so I was giving him specific advice.

Comment: @ChrisW I referenced the other answer in my comment. I do agree that it is bad to not offer an explain on the better alternative.

Comment: @pllee You did reference the 'other' answer, but you didn't answer the question yourself, and neither did you up-vote the 'other other' accepted answer (which has received no votes in either direction). It's one thing to criticize (and I won't tell you not to) but it would be more constructive if you explained, somewhere, what the better alternative is.

Comment: I didn't answer the question outright I did say this: `Overriding the initComponent on the child instance isn't pretty but it is much better` .  To me that clearly states the better alternative.

Answer (score -3):

There's a great risk of flame wars with such approach. Consider 2 groups of people, one thinks that A is bad practice and B is good practice, and the second thinks opposite.

In my opinion, it's better to upvote answer you think is better and reserve downvoting for the situations, when the answer doesn't asnwer the question or is not working.